# How to understand SSH tunnel creation to remote host through jump server and automating it with Python

Tags: python, putty, ssh-tunnel

Below are the manual steps we perform to connect to remote linux server through putty,

1. Provide the below command in command prompt,

   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty" -P 4422 xxxx.yyyy.com\eid@zzzz.yyyy.com\eid@servername@aaaa.yyyy.com -L 50001:servername:22`
2. It will automatically open a putty session where we will be providing password(system pwd) and then it will prompt for rsa passcode which we need to provide by generating it.

After performing the above operations it will login to the remote server.

After doing some research on these I found that they are using a jump host to connect to remote host and they are performing local port forwarding.

Is there anyway to automate this remote host logging in and perform some operations like moving a file to certain path and copy some files from local to remote host and execute a C program by providing appropriate options?

Before this logging in implementation, we can directly login to the server using username and password and I automated it through paramiko library in Python. Please find the below code for reference,

```
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        # Set SSH key parameters to auto accept unknown hosts
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        #connect to host
        client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=pwd)
        with SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=10, display=True) as interact:
            interact.send('cd ' +scripts_path)
            interact.send('./xxxx')
            interact.send('T')
            interact.send('A')
```

Comment: To perform ad-hoc automation tasks on a remote server, you could look at Ansible.

Comment: Halfer - Thanks for the information I gone through that tool it have many awesome features. But any specific example or reference related to my query would be better.